# In F#, is there a shortcut for creating a record type with a primary key used for equality and sorting comparison?

Tags: .net, orm, f#, dto

I know that the F# compiler can generate default implementations of `IEquatable<T>` and `IComparable<T>`, as well as overrides for the default `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for records and classes.  But these implementations use all fields in comparison.  I have a few DTO types I need to create, where equality and sort order should be based solely on a primary key field.  Is there some handy mechanism like an attribute for this?

Here is my class:
(I've probably made a few F# grammar errors.  Still kinda new.)

```
type Customer() =
    member val Id = 0 with get, set
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val PhoneNumber = "" with get, set
```

Can I do something like this:

```
[<CompareByKey>]
type Customer() =
    [<PrimaryKey>] member val Id = 0 with get, set
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val PhoneNumber = "" with get, set
```

instead of this:

```
type Customer() =
    member val Id = 0 with get, set
    member val Name = "" with get, set
    member val PhoneNumber = "" with get, set

    override Equals(obj) = 
        match obj with
        | :? Customer as c -> this.Id = c.Id
        | _ -> false

    override GetHashCode() = hash this.Id

    interface IEquatable<Customer> with
        member Equals(c) = this.Id = c.Id

    interface IComparable<Customer> with
        member CompareTo(c) = this.Id.CompareTo(c.Id)
```

**EDIT:**

I think this may be a problem better solved in C# with an abstract base class.  (Also implementable in F#, but it kinda starts getting un-idiomatic.)

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TEntity> : 
    IEquatable<TEntity>, 
    IComparable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase<TEntity> {

    protected EntityBase(int id) { 
        this.Id = id; 
    }

    public int Id { get; }

    public sealed override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();

    public sealed override bool Equals(object obj) => 
        Equals(this, obj as TEntity);

    public bool Equals(TEntity other) => 
        (other != null) && (this.Id == other.Id);

    public int CompareTo(TEntity other) => 
        (other == null) ? 1 : this.Id.CompareTo(other.Id);

}
```

Comment: Sorting isn't a problem as long as the primary key is first.  Are you certain, however, that you want to say that `{ ID="Alice"; Office="Room 10" }` is equal to `{ ID="Alice"; Office="Room 11" }`?

Comment: Well, everything is being pulled directly from SQL and mapped with an ORM to these objects, so as long as the app I'm writing doesn't corrupt the state of these objects while they're in memory it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I'd also very much like to make all these fields readonly, but I need Dapper to be able to initialize them.  I know there are a few different ways of declaring properties in F#, but I'm not familiar with all the subtleties yet.  As far as I know Dapper needs a constructor with all parameters (which I can do) or a parameterless constructor and properties with setters (which may be private).

Comment: I haven't done any ORM work with F# but as you've no doubt noticed ORMs are typically incompatible with immutable data types.  F# has compromised a bit in the direction of mutability, but I'm not sure whether these compromises make it better than C# for defining DTO types.

Comment: Yes, serializers as well.

Comment: To support (de)serialization, you can adorn a record type with the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute. Regarding the question about only using a single key for equality comparison, then what's the use case?

Comment: Depending ob the use case you might be better off using datastructures supporting custom comparison (`IEqualityComparer`) than implementing all the ceremony needed for classes / records.

Comment: @phoog For dealing with ORM that don't understand constructors, there's `CLIMutable`. Json.NET, Dapper, AutoMapper, ... have no problems with records. So I found F# to be *great* for DTOs.

Comment: @CaringDev thanks for the tip. I will look into those ORMs, none of which I have investigated before.

Comment: @MarkSeemann The use case is that I have several sequences of thousands (up to a million possibly) records each that need to be sorted, joined, queried, and so on, so I want really cheap comparisons.

Comment: Is it a performance concern, then?

Comment: It's a mixture of performance and semantic clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to pull out the primary key. Reflection can be costly, so make sure you are only getting one call to the search for keys per type (I've left some `printfn` in the code below so that I can double-check)

```
open System
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>]
type PrimaryKeyAttribute() =
    inherit Attribute()
[<CLIMutable()>]
type Customer =
    {
        [<PrimaryKey>] 
        Id: int
        Name: string
    }
let getPrimaryKey<'T, 'U when 'U:> IComparable> (): 'T -> 'U =
    printfn "Starting to search for keys."
    typeof<'T>.GetProperties()
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun p -> 
        let attr = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof<PrimaryKeyAttribute>, false)
        attr.Length > 0
    )
    |> function 
        | Some p -> 
            (fun t -> p.GetMethod.Invoke(t, [| |]) :?> 'U)
        | _ -> failwith "No PrimaryKey attribute found"
```

Sorting a list of customers now becomes:

```
let customers = 
    [
        { Id = 4; Name = "Alice" }
        { Id = 1; Name = "Eve" }
        { Id = 1; Name = "Charlie" }
        { Id = 1; Name = "Bob" }
    ]
let sorted = 
    customers
    |> List.sortBy (getPrimaryKey())
```

and you'll get:

```
val sorted : Customer list =
 [{Id = 1;
 Name = "Eve";}; {Id = 1;
                 Name = "Charlie";}; {Id = 1;
                                      Name = "Bob";}; {Id = 4;
                                                       Name = "Alice";}]
```

Whereas the normal sort would give you Bob; Charlie; Eve; Alice. You may want to pre-compute the key getter for each type:

```
let getCustomerKey<'U when 'U:> IComparable> : Customer -> 'U = 
    getPrimaryKey() 
let sorted2 = 
    customers
    |> List.sortBy getCustomerKey
```

And, as others have noted already, `[<CLIMutable()>]` is helpful when working with code that relies on default constructors and mutation. See the [documentation here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2012/07/19/more-about-f-3-0-language-features/)

Comment: Have you ever run into a situation where the supposed costliness of reflection actually caused a noticeable or meaningful degradation of performance? I have not.

Comment: If you're not careful, you can end up with code that, for example, invokes the call to `GetCustomProperties` for each comparison, and then you're clearly paying a lot. This may sound trivial, but it is not always easy to spot. When used with care, I agree that there's little to be worried.

Comment: For example: If I write `let getCustomerKey = getPrimaryKey()`, the compiler complains about value restriction, and suggests to either add annotation or make the arguments explicit. If I then change to `let getCustomerKey v = getPrimaryKey() v` I get 4 calls to `getPrimaryKey` instead of 1 when sorting the list.

Comment: I understand the principle, but I wonder whether anyone has actually had a performance problem caused by superfluous use of reflection.  If I understand correctly the performance of reflection has been significantly improved through the use of caching, but it retains this reputation for being inefficient, mostly without justification since .NET 2.0. I've seen people writing code to cache the results of reflection calls, unaware that the framework is also caching these results. Premature optimization and all that.

Comment: In our team we've had two major incidents where superfluous use reflection had slowed down a production system to the point of becoming unusable. That was on .NET 4